# Sublime Text 3 - indentation after self-closing HTML5 tag

Tags: html, tags, sublimetext3, indentation

I'm writing HTML5 in Sublime Text 3 and not explicitly closing self-closing tags, i.e.

```html
<nav>
  <image src="assets/apps-btn.png">
  <image src="assets/navbar-logo.png">
</nav>
```

However, Sublime Text 3 is indenting automatically and expecting me to explicitly close these tags, generating the closing tag `</image>` when I type `</` to close the `<nav>` tag with `</nav>`, i.e.

```html
<nav>
 <image src="assets/apps-btn.png">
 </image>
  <image src="assets/navbar-logo.png">
  </image>
  </nav>
```

Can anyone tell me how to change this please?  I still want to use auto-indentation, but want to change how Sublime Text 3 treats self-closing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as an `<image>` element in HTML, so the parsing rules (for unknown elements) mean that the end tag is required.

If you use an element where the end tag is forbidden (such as `<img>`) then you should see the correct indentation.